# Can I do bulk updates with the microsoft graph API? Specifically contacts

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the microsoft graph php sdk to manipulate a user's contacts. I can do CRUD operations on individual contacts, but I am trying to figure out if it is possible to process multiple contacts in a single request. This works fine for adding a single client:

```
 $graph=new Graph;
 $graph->setAccessToken($token);
 $graph->createRequest('POST', $url)
 ->attachBody($contact)
 ->setReturnType(Contact::class)
 ->execute();
```

For bulk I tried

```
 ->attachBody([$contact1, $contact2, $contact3]);
```

and I get the 400 error:

> `"code": "BadRequest",`
> `"message": "Empty Payload. JSON content expected.",`

I got the same error when trying in [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), POSTing to 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts` with this body:

```
[
  {
    "emailAddresses": [
      {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "address": "jdoe@example.com"
      }
    ],
    "givenName": "John"
  },
  {
    "emailAddresses": [
      {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "address": "jdoe@example.com"
      }
    ],
    "givenName": "John"
  }
]
```

Is there a way to do this or is it not supported? I couldn't find a mention of it either way in the documentation.

Sometimes I have to add thousands of contacts and doing 1 per request seems tedious.

Same question for all the update operations: post, patch, delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Graph has a [Batching feature](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching) specifically for this type of scenario. Each operation is still against a single record, but batching allows you to make one call to execute up to 20 operations:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/me/contacts",
      "headers":{
         "Content-Type":"application/json"
      },
      "body": {
        "emailAddresses": [
          {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "address": "jdoe@example.com"
          }
        ],
        "givenName": "John"
      }
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/me/contacts",
        "headers":{
           "Content-Type":"application/json"
        },
        "body": {
          "emailAddresses": [
            {
              "name": "John Doe",
              "address": "jdoe@example.com"
            }
          ],
          "givenName": "John"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/me/contacts",
        "headers":{
           "Content-Type":"application/json"
        },
        "body": {
          "emailAddresses": [
            {
              "name": "John Doe",
              "address": "jdoe@example.com"
            }
          ],
          "givenName": "John"
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Cool! 1) Is this exposed in the php sdk anywhere? and 2)Where is the 20 limit documented?

Comment: nvm on the 2nd one

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific batching functionality in the SDK (disclosure, I'm not an expert on the PHP SDK). That said, you should be able to POST this payload just as you would any other payload through the SDK.

Comment: I am getting the error `Write request id : 1 does not contain Content-Type header or body.` I get that error with my own code, and I get the same error when pasting your sample directly into graph explorer.

Comment: You need to add a contact type header to any request with a body to tell it what's in the body, so in this case, Content-Type:application/json. After adding that, it worked!